# How to pass component constructor in React props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to pass component constructor in React props?

I'm a beginner for React. So below example may make it clear what I am trying to achieve.

#### Example:

PorkComponent:

```js
const PorkComponent = ({ children, variant }: PorkComponentProps) => {
  return (
    <motion.div>
      ...
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

DuckComponent:

```js
const DuckComponent = ({ children, variant }: DuckComponentProps) => {
  return (
    <motion.div>
      ...
    </motion.div>
  );
};
```

The `Lunch` component will contains `PorkComponent` or `DuckComponent` Based on LunchProps.meatType.

```js
type LunchProps = {
  meatType: React.ComponentType;
};

const Lunch = (props: LunchProps) => {
 return (
    <props.meatType> // Here it will return PorkComponent or DuckComponent based on what props.meatType.
  );

}
```

Sure I can use something like:

```js
const Lunch = (props: LunchProps) => {
 return (
    if (props.isPork) {
      < PorkComponent >
    } else(props.isDuck) {
      < DuckComponent >
    }
    ....
  );

}
```

But I don't want to have multiple IFELSE check in `Lunch` component. Instead, I want the caller to specify the "meat type", like `<Lunch meatType= PorkComponent>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write :

```
const Lunch = (props: LunchProps) => <props.meatType />;

<Lunch meatType={DuckComponent} />
```

Here is an [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2ysxf1?file=src/App.js)

Comment: You can also write: `const { meatType: MeatType } = props;` and then `<MeatType />`

Comment: I just tried <props.meatType /> without destructuring and it works. Capital letter is required only when you define the component.

Comment: you are right, if there is a dot in the expression, it's working. `<props.meatType />` works, but `<meatType />` doesn't work

Comment: Square bracket notation doesn't work either - props["meatType"]. Probably there is a constraint in JSX compilation, like we have to use "className" instead of "class"

Answer (score 3):

I recently saw this someone shared on Twitter,

```
const MeatComponents = {
  'pork': <PorkComponent />
  'duck': <DuckComponent />
}

const Lunch = (props) => {
 return MeatComponent[props.meatType]
}

 // usage

 <Lunch meatType='pork' />
 <Lunch meatType='duck' />
```

Or you could just use,

```
const Lunch = ({ children }) => {
 return <>{children}</>
}

// usage

<Lunch>
  <PorkComponent />
</Lunch>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the rendered component directly instead:

```
// in Lunch component
return (<div>{props.meatType}</div>);
```

```
<Lunch meatType={<PorkComponent />} />
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBRbxN)

---

If you just want to return the given component, simply use:

```
return props.meatType;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass component functions as props. You almost got the answer.

```
const Lunch = (props) => {
 return (
    // React.createElement(props.meatType, {}, null)
    <props.meatType /> // this is valid, I have tested before replying.
  );
}

// then
<Lunch meatType={PorkComponent} />
// or
<Lunch meatType={DuckComponent} />
// even this works and renders a div
<Lunch meatType="div" />
```

Comment: looks like `props.meatType` is not a valid tag

Comment: @irous I think you are confusing with the rule "react components must start with capital letter". props.meatType is passed into createElement function. its value can be component function or string(html tag).

Comment: no, I'm just not sure. have you tried running it?

Comment: @irous  yes to make sure I have tried various combinations just now. Feel free to try yourself. Any variable results with a component definition or html tag string is valid. Furthermore you can use rest operator to piggyback props too.